# Select stament with division operator mysql using pandas

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|  CategoryCount  | frequency |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 0               | 123       |
| 12              | 234       |
| 15              | 456       |
| 0               | 678       |
| 25              | 890       |
| 0               | 145       |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

it has 300 rows

I want to find total no. of count,where the frequency is less than 75%
i am writing this query:

```
select sum(CategoryCount) 
from Session_category_analysis 
where frequency/sum(frequency) < 0.75;
```

but i am getting error as

> ERROR 1111 (HY000):Invalid use of group function

i also tried using this query:

```
select CategoryCount , frequency 
from Session_category_analysis 
where frequency/sum(frequency) < 0.75 
group by  CategoryCount ;
```

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

also this query, but failed

```
 select CategoryCount from  Session_category_analysis 
 where(select frequency/sum(frequency) 
   from Session_category_analysis 
   where frequency/sum(frequency)  < 0.75
);
```

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: is that really your table or is it an intermediate result? if so, show the original table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(CategoryCount) 
from Session_category_analysis 
where (frequency * 100 / (select sum(frequency) from Session_category_analysis)) < 75
```

Comment: what if i have this table in pandas dataframe,
how do i execute this query?

Comment: I don't use python. If you can't figure it out, ask another question about it.

Comment: shouldn't i use count(CategoryCount) instead of sum(CategoryCount)
since i want to find the total no. of category count

Comment: `count()` counts the records. `sum()` sums up the values in the records. Do you want to count only the number of records?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of where, you can use the having clause:

```
select sum(CategoryCount) as 's'
from Session_category_analysis
having s/sum(frequency) < 0.75;
```

Comment: what if i have this table in pandas dataframe,
how do i execute this query?